# finding singular points of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the singular points of the function

$$ f(z)= z^4/(z-z^5)
$$

which would have the singular points $0,1,-1,i,-i$.

But I am not sure if I should simplify it to

$$ f(z)= z^3/(1-z^4)
$$

which would have the singular points $1,-1$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you simplified it, you are assuming that $z\neq 0$.

Comment: From the regularity point of view, $0$ is a "false" singularity. If you are simply looking at the definition set, then $z=0$ must be excluded. So all depends on the level of the explanation you want.

Answer (score 2):

$z^{4}=1$ does not imply $z =\pm 1$. So in the second form also the singularities are $\pm 1, \pm i$. $\, 0$ has to be excluded from the domain but the function has a removable singularity at $0$.

Comment: Perfect thank you